# In inno setup how to set the unins000.exe with product name, product version and copyrights properties

Tags: inno-setup, uninstallation

I have created an installer using inno setup. Everything works fine but after installation unins000.exe will be generated, this exe doesn't have product name, product version and copyrights properties set. Can any one explain me how to build the installer so that unins000.exe will contain these fields.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you cannot set those values and really, there's no need to do it.  That file is put into the {app} directory (where your application is installed).

Why do you want to set those values?

Comment: This is needed to certify an application by some institutions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completeley sure what you want to do.

What I understood: you want to change some of the properties of your unistall executable. This part of the InnoSetup-Help might help:
[UninstallFilesDir](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstallfilesdir). Close to this Page there is more information on uninstall.