# Inno Setup uninstaller VersionInfo

Tags: inno-setup

I use Inno Setup for my installers. I have a problem with VersionInfo inside `unins000.exe`. For filling VersionInfo in installer I used directives `AppPublisher`, `AppCopyright` and etc. But it doesn't affect setup uninstaller `unins000.exe`.

Google and help doesn't know anything about this issue. I investigated Inno Setup sources and found appending VersionInfo just for setup file:

```pascal
        { Update version info }
        AddStatus(SCompilerStatusUpdatingVersionInfo);
        UpdateVersionInfo(ExeFile, VersionInfoVersion, VersionInfoProductVersion, VersionInfoCompany,
          VersionInfoDescription, VersionInfoTextVersion,
          VersionInfoCopyright, VersionInfoProductName, VersionInfoProductTextVersion);

        { For some reason, on Win95 the date/time of the EXE sometimes
          doesn't get updated after it's been written to so it has to
          manually set it. (I don't get it!!) }
        UpdateTimeStamp(ExeFile.Handle);
      finally
        ExeFile.Free;
      end;
    end;

    { Sign }
    if SignTools.Count > 0 then begin
      AddStatus(SCompilerStatusSigningSetup);
      Sign(ExeFileName);
    end;
  except
    EmptyOutputDir(False);
    raise;
  end;
```

But I can't found this routines in uninstaller compile code.

Anybody know, is possible place version info to `unins000.exe`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inno Setup does not support this.

You would have to modify the version info yourself on compile time.

Imo, the only way to access the uninstaller executable before it is linked into the installer is to abuse the [`SignTool`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_signtool) "callback". The command set to `SignTool` can actually do anything with the executable, not only "sign" it. But it has to "sign" it in any case (Inno Setup explicitly checks that the executable was signed after the "tool" finishes).

You can achieve that by setting `SignTool` to a batch file (or other script) that will run the actual `signtool.exe` in the end, but before that, it will modify the version info (e.g. using [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) command-line).

Comment: Great and very simple idea! Thank you!

P.S. I'm already recompile ISCmplr.dll from github sources. Dll succesfully compiled, but doesn't work properly(( Now I go to try use batch file for rewriting VersionInfo and signing an uninstaller. Thank you again)!

Comment: Here is similar question without answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885948/in-inno-setup-how-to-set-the-unins000-exe-with-product-name-product-version-and Can you answer this question too, or can I copy paste your answer there?

Comment: @EugeneMala Thanks for pointing this out. I've marked that question as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: OK, I see. I use this technique to [change binary flags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29072495/850848). And that works. Possibly an EXE file header is not included into the test.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the accepted solution does not work, because the [SignTool](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_signtool) "callback" can not be abused in this way. Digging into Inno Setup sources, I found that the compiler uses the [following](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/master/Projects/Compile.pas#L8096) verification after signing uninstall executable:

```
  { Sanity check: Remove the signature (in memory) and verify that
    the signed file is identical byte-for-byte to the original }
```

I found a quick solution for the problem. Inno Setup uses `Setup.e32` file as a template for `uninst000.exe`.

As Inno Setup is completely portable - you can maintain a separate copy of Inno Setup binaries folder (default is `%ProgramFiles%\Inno Setup 5\`) for each project that needs to have the custom version info in the uninstaller.

You have to modify the version info of `Setup.e32` file in each copy of Inno Setup binaries.